# Can't map local ip address to localhost

Tags: android, macos, ruby-on-rails-4, osx-elcapitan

I Have 2 applications:

- a **rails api** running on my mac like this: `rails s`
- an **android client app** talking with the rails api from mi phone

Well, the apps are not talking yet...

I'm trying to perform a `POST` to `http://192.168.1.34:3000/api/uploads` from the device, but I'm getting `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`on chrome.

So, I try to execute the same request from the computer and it returns the same `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`.

When I execute `http://localhost:3000/api/uploads`, from the computer it works fine.

So, I think the local ip is not mapping to localhost. How can I do this?

I' using:

- `OSX El Capitan 10.11.1`
- `Google Chorem Version 48.0.2564.23 beta (64-bit)`

this is how my `/etc/hosts` file looks like:

```
##
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
##
127.0.0.1       leansmac
127.0.0.1       localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost
```

ping it's working too:

```
ping 192.168.1.34                                                                                                               
PING 192.168.1.34 (192.168.1.34): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 192.168.1.34: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.091 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.34: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.070 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.34: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.138 ms
```

> the mac and the phone are connected to the same wifi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's an issue with Rails not accepting connections from outside except localhost.

Please try the following :

[Allow public connections to local Ruby on Rails Development Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9282689/allow-public-connections-to-local-ruby-on-rails-development-server)

> The simplest way requires no additional installations: just add a single option to your rails server (or rails s) command when you start up the server:

```
rails s --binding=0.0.0.0
```

> The 0.0.0.0 address means "listen to requests from anywhere." On many systems, the default is 127.0.0.1, which means "listen to requests from localhost only."
>   (If you don't also specify a -p or --port option, then the port shall be 3000, as usual.)

Comment: I know I can use the binding. I really want to do this: `http://my-app.192.168.1.34.xip.io/api/uploads.json` and does not work just adding the `--binding` option. I did not mention it, because I really want to access to `http://192.168.1.34:3000` like I did once (God knows when was that)

Comment: That shouldn't be too hard. I think this is the points are : 1. Your computer should resolve to my-app.192.168.1.34.xip.io. 2: Binding should be 0.0.0.0 and --port should be 80

Comment: I'm using pow. I don't want to set anything. This is what I want: http://pow.cx/manual.html#section_2.1.5. I think my problem is not related with pow. Thats why I've simplified the question. Maybe was not a good idea...

Comment: Can you check steps from here : http://superuser.com/questions/299425/how-can-i-resolve-an-internal-ip-address-to-a-hostname-on-os-x/299431   nslookup http://my-app.192.168.1.34.xip.io